# Why I get java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field xxxx of type I in class Lpl/myapp/mobile/main/BR; or its superclasses?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I have configurated databinding in android app project like below.
and I get error on every field which is defined in xml file (as variable). I don't know if it's related but I use the newest android studio.

I use only debug. Yes also i try clean project. ivalidate and restart android studio. Unistall app and isntal to clean device. I also made factory reset on my Mi Box.

```
android {

compileSdkVersion "28.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "pl.myapp.app"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 28
    versionName "1"
    resConfigs "en", "pl"
}

buildFeatures {
    dataBinding = true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    uat {
        applicationIdSuffix ".uat"

        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
    }

    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"

        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
    }

}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

lintOptions {
    disable "NotSibling"
    abortOnError false
}
```

}

but I get exception (and app crashes) with:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field episode of type I in class Lpl/myapp/mobile/tv/BR; or its superclasses (declaration of 'pl.myapp.mobile.tv.BR' appears in /data/app/pl.myapp.app.atv.dev-WdbOpjR9fmv54PzXTST74w==/base.apk:classes2.dex)
    at pl.myapp.mobile.tv.databinding.MainSectionItemCardBindingImpl.setEpisode(MainSectionItemCardBindingImpl.java:88)
    at pl.myapp.mobile.tv.ui.gui.view.cards.SectionCardPresenter.onBindViewHolder(SectionCardPresenter.kt:25)
    at pl.myapp.mobile.tv.ui.gui.view.cards.SectionCardPresenter.onBindViewHolder(SectionCardPresenter.kt:12)
    at pl.myapp.mobile.tv.ui.BasePresenter.onBindViewHolder(BasePresenter.kt:35)
    at androidx.leanback.widget.Presenter.onBindViewHolder(Presenter.java:140)
    at androidx.leanback.widget.ItemBridgeAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ItemBridgeAdapter.java:400)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
    at androidx.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager.measureScrapChild(GridLayoutManager.java:1288)
    at androidx.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager.processRowSizeSecondary(GridLayoutManager.java:1372)
    at androidx.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager.onMeasure(GridLayoutManager.java:1476)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3593)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
```

Fragment of MainSectionItemCardBindingImpl class:

```
    public void setEpisode(@Nullable pl.myapp.mobile.tv.ui.model.MainCarouselItem Episode) {
       this.mEpisode = Episode;
       synchronized(this) {
           mDirtyFlags |= 0x1L;
       }
       notifyPropertyChanged(BR.episode); //line 88
       super.requestRebind();
   }
```

Fragment of SectionCardPresenter class:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: DataBoundLeanbackViewHolder<MainSectionItemCardBinding>, item: MainCarouselItem?) {
    viewHolder.binding.episode = item //line 25
    viewHolder.binding.root.setOnClickListener { onItemClickListener?.invoke(item) }
```

and fragment of xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
                name="episode"
                type="pl.myapp.mobile.tv.ui.model.MainCarouselItem"/>

    </data>
```

all other binding are working like access to views via binding object.

Comment: is this happening for a debug build or a release build?

Comment: have you tried clean install or invalidate cache?

Comment: I use only debug. Yes also i try clean project. ivalidate and restart android studio. Unistall app and isntal to clean device. I also made factory reset on my Mi Box. Without no success. :(

Comment: try changing the name of your layout

Comment: its possible that its trying to inflate a completely different layout with thesame name.

Comment: I inflate using this: MainSectionItemCardBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context),parent,false)

Comment: Seems like you are using multi module project.....for me, two modules had the same layout with similar databinding. I needed to change the layout name to make it work

Comment: In my case it was because I used multi module project and had 2 Android modules with the exact same package declaration in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Changing the package declaration in one of the modules solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case my xml file was in different module/package which was not accessible
Check if xml is in same package if not then move it to same package where your code is written.